# iOS NSString initwithbytes returns null

Tags: ios, nsstring, keychain

I have following snippet:

```
uint8_t* cipherBuffer;
size_t cipherBufferSize;

sanityCheck = SecKeyEncrypt(keyRef, kSecPaddingPKCS1, nonce, (size_t)sizeof(nonce)/sizeof(nonce[0]), cipherBuffer, &cipherBuffeSize);

NSString* encryptString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:cipherBuffer length:cipherBufferSize encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autoRelease];
```

Here, I always get `nil` for `encryptString`.

Any suggestion where I made mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You assume that you are getting a result that is in valid UTF-8 format. That is very unlikely. NSString* is for text. Encrypted data is pure data, not text. To put the encrypted data into an Objective-C object, you probably want to use NSData.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.I understand your reason. What I want to do is to send encrypted data to server using webservice. And this is why I want to convert it to string.

Comment: @sam18 One more reason to use `NSData`. (You send data to servers, not strings.)

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe let me see if I can use NSData datatype to send to http request

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe you are right I cannot use `NSString`. All I need to do is to encode `NSData` to `Base64` and then I can use `NSString`. Now here I again stuck with string length If I encode `NSData` to `Base64` my final string length is higher then the modulus length which result into failure. any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

The docs say:

> If the length of the byte string is greater than the specified length a nil value is returned.

Have you double checked the length of cipherBuffer is equal to cipherBufferSize?